# How to Remove Whole Index of List in a JSON

Tags: mysql, json

I have a JSON Values Like This.

```
{
"CHEQUE":[
{
"Cheque_No":"1",
"Cheque_Date":"2018-05-30",
"Cheque_Amount":"10000",
"Bank_Name":"ICICI"
},

{
"Cheque_No":"2",
"Cheque_Date":"2018-05-30",
"Cheque_Amount":"20000",
"Bank_Name":"ICICI"
},
    {
"Cheque_No":"2",
"Cheque_Date":"2018-05-30",
"Cheque_Amount":"20000",
"Bank_Name":"SBI"
}

]

}'
```

How can i Remove Entire Index of 2 in a CHEQUE list using the search key SBI for Bank name?.

I need to Do this is in Mysql Stored Procedure without Store Values in DB. This is what I  have tried:

```
    CREATE DEFINER = root @ PROCEDURE SP_TEST(
        IN ls_json JSON,
        OUT Message VARCHAR(1000)
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            JSON_REMOVE(
                ls_json,
                CONCAT('$.CHEQUE[0].Bank_Name[0]')
            )
        INTO ls_json;
        #SELECT JSON_REMOVE(ls_json,JSON_SEARCH(ls_json,'ALL', 
        CONCAT('$.CHEQUE[0].Cheque_No[*]')))
    INTO ls_json; #select 
    JSON_SEARCH(ls_json, 'one', 10000);
    SELECT
        ls_json;
    END
```

Comment: I need to Do in it Mysql Stored Procedure.

Comment: So.. you haven't tried anything?

Comment: I tried a Stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_TEST` (
  IN `_ls_json` JSON,
  IN `_bank_name` VARCHAR(64)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE `_base` CHAR(11) DEFAULT '$.CHEQUE[*]';
  DECLARE `_base_attr` CHAR(10) DEFAULT '.Bank_Name';
  DECLARE `_element` VARCHAR(1024);
  `_loop`: LOOP
    SET `_element` :=
      JSON_SEARCH(
        `_ls_json`,
        'one',
        `_bank_name`,
        NULL,
        CONCAT(`_base`, `_base_attr`)
      );
    IF (`_element` IS NOT NULL) THEN
      SET `_ls_json` :=
        JSON_REMOVE(
          `_ls_json`,
          JSON_UNQUOTE(
            REPLACE(`_element`, `_base_attr`, '')
          )
        );
    ELSE
      LEAVE `_loop`;
    END IF;
  END LOOP `_loop`;
  SELECT JSON_PRETTY(`_ls_json`);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sq52zrNE3QkrkrfqmAtY3d/0).